# Changing background color in vim at a certain column

Tags: vim, macvim

I'd like to be able to highlight the wrap margin/text width in vim by changing the background color (or maybe just a line?).  A lot of IDEs have this.  I mocked up what I'm talking about:

[image]

Anyone know if this can be done in macvim or gvim?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
:match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'
```

It will highlight text beyond 80 characters, you can replace '80' with whatever wrap-width you have. However, it will only highlight the characters that exceed the width, and then only on lines that are actually longer than the width.

Check http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_long_lines for more info, but they all pretty much accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Yes!  That works well; I wasn't wrapping my head around the fact that this is a way to "highlight long lines" (which your link is the first hit for).

Answer (score 35):

Since Vim 7.3 it's possible to have columns highlighted like this:

[image: Screenshot of MacVim with highlighted column]

To set it to the current `textwidth`:

```
:set cc=+1
```

Or you can set it to predefined value:

```
:set cc=80
```

You can change its color like this:

```
:hi ColorColumn ctermbg=lightgrey guibg=lightgrey
```

See help for more details:

```
:help colorcolumn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
autocmd FileType * execute "setlocal colorcolumn=" . join(range(&textwidth,250), ',')
highlight ColorColumn guibg=#303030 ctermbg=0
```

Big problem with this is that the colorcolumn highlighting has higher priority then hlsearch! So basically you wont be able to see highlighted search items beyond that margin...

Comment: You will obviously have to pick the right bg colors for your colorscheme.