# How to configure Vim word wrap options vimrc

Tags: vim

I'm trying to configure Vim so that it always wraps at x-number of columns automatically, at all times such as in this other editor that I provided a screenshot of-

[image] [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want *hard wrapping*, i.e. real reformatting of the text by inserting newline characters, the `'textwidth'` setting (as outlined in suspectus's answer) is the key. You need to reformat existing text, e.g. via the `gq` command.

For *soft wrapping*, i.e. where long lines just appear to be broken in the editor window, `:set wrap` will always fill the entire available window space; you cannot restrict that to take less. Either resize the Vim window, or add a **padding buffer** to the right that restricts the available space to the current window. For the latter, my [LimitWindowSize plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3238) may be helpful.

Answer (score 12):

Use `:set wrap` and `:set textwidth=N` . For permanent effect add the wrap settings to the `vim` start-up file `.vimrc`

```
set wrap
set textwidth=X
```

To apply the wrapping to an existing file, move to the start of the file (you can use `gg` to do this). Then type `gqG` to apply the re-formatting to the entire file.

Also setting a margin may be useful:

```
set wrapmargin=0
```

Comment: This isn't working for me unfortunately, I've tried setting them at run time with ":" and also in vimrc just using "set wrap" etc.

Comment: Edited soluton - does that help?

Comment: It doesn't consistently wrap it, but it does if you use "ggqG", a one time thing, I was looking for something that would do it automatically and persistently.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the second screenshot, you seemed to want soft-wrap. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/989317/1743811) suggests a way to achieve a soft-wrap effect .

I'm generalizing the solution a bit compared to the one I referred to, but basically

1. use `:set nuw` to see how many columns the line numbers are occupying, let's call this `nuw`.
2. then use `:set columns=x` where `x` = (the number of columns you want + `nuw`).

Note that the `columns` is automatically reset to window width once you resize the window, so this manual setting is not persistent.