# How to highlight past dynamically-specified column in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to make a function im my .vimrc to highlight all columns past #, where # is specified in an autocmd for each file type.

For instance, if I wanted Python files to highlight past column 80, but Java files past column 100 I would like to be able to do so as:

```
autocmd FileType python :call HighlightPastCol(80)
autocmd FileType java :call HighlightPastCol(100)
```

I am trying to write the `HighlightPastCol(col)` function as follows:

```
function HighlightPastCol(col)
    let pastColRegex = '\v\%>' . a:col . 'v.\+'
    match ErrorMsg pastColRegex
endfunction
```

Where `pastColRegex` is of the form `'\%>#v.+'` and `#` is the column passed in to the function. I got this regex from [a related stackoverflow question, but with a static column number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830645/changing-background-color-in-vim-at-a-certain-column) instead of the dynamic column specification I want. That regex has been working for me, but I don't want to keep hand-crafting regexes like that for every file type that I want to have this behavior but with a different column count.

The issue I'm running into is that vimscript throws an error on:

```
match ErrorMsg pastColRegex
```

stating 'Invalid argument: pastColRegex'.

If there's a better way to go about doing this or a plugin with this functionality, that would be appreciated, though I would still like to know why this approach is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to add delimiters and execute `match` dynamically. I think this is about right:

```
function HighlightPastCol(col)
    let pastColRegex = '/\v\%>' . a:col . 'v.\+/'
    exec 'match ErrorMsg ' . pastColRegex
endfunction
```

There’s also the `colorcolumn` option, which doesn’t behave in exactly the same way, but is quite convenient.